# How to enable <br> on custom shortcodes

Tags: shortcode, wysiwyg

I have created a shortcode that displays a table in WordPress:

```
function table_data($atts, $content = null)
{

    $defaults = shortcode_atts(array(
        'data' => 'th:data1,td:data2,td:data3'
    ), $atts);

    $table_data = explode(",", esc_attr($defaults['data']));
    $result = '<tr>';

    foreach ($table_data as $data) {
        $split = explode(":", $data);
        $result .= '<' . $split[0] . '>' . $split[1] . '</' . $split[0] . '>';
    }

    $result .= '</tr>';
    return $result;
}

add_shortcode('table_data', 'table_data');


function table_anchor($atts, $content = null)
{
    $defaults = shortcode_atts(array(
        'scroll' => 'false'
    ), $atts);

    if (esc_attr($defaults['scroll']) == 'true') {
        $result = '<div class="article-tbl-wrap"><table class="article-tbl scrollable"><tbody>';
    } else {
        $result = '<div class="article-tbl-wrap"><table class="article-tbl"><tbody>';
    }

    $result .= do_shortcode($content);
    $result .= '</tbody></table></div>';

    return $result;
}

add_shortcode('table_anchor', 'table_anchor');
```

This is working properly. However, when I insert "< br >" tags in the shortcode, it just prints "< br >" in the page. Have I done something wrong?

Here is how I use the shortcodes in the editor:

```
[table_anchor scroll="false"]
[table_data data="th:テスト,th:80.0%,td:testers<br>"]
[table_data data="th:テスト,td:80.0%,td:testers2<br>"]
[/table_anchor]
```

Let me know how to print the "< br >" tags as new lines. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [esc_attr](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/) in your `table_data` function. This will encode the html in your variable in such a way that it is no longer recognized as html. So the browser will display "<br>" rather than insert a line break.

Comment: thanks for your answer!